# php5-fpm doesn't work with php-apc on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: php, ubuntu, apc

Packages php5-fpm and php-apc installed from ubuntu 10.10 official repo. APC configuration:

*/etc/php5/conf.d/apc.ini*

```
extension=apc.so
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=128M
```

Afret php5-fpm restart:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function apc_exists() in /var/www/.../application/models/user_model.php on line 271
```

phpinfo(); says apc module is loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apc_exists needed apc >= 3.1.4 but ubuntu 10.10 has 3.1.3p1-2

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install php5-fpm
nano /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini
```

add ==> `extension=apc.so` in your dynamic extensions section
restart and APC should be working fine, double check with your php info file